# Criteria for dispatching requests for multi-threaded GAE apps

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, dispatcher

I am trying to understand how GAE evaluates when to dispatch a request to an instance when your JAVA app on GAE has multi-threading "true".

how many concurrent threads (requests) will a 600 Mhz instance run?

What is the criteria to dispatch a request as a new thread versus hold off and potentially spawn a new instance?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on what the request handler does.  The best way to find out is to benchmark it, since it depends on many things.

Comment: The benchmarking is producing erratic results on GAE for multiple sequential invocations of the same request processing an indentical data set. Part of the variation is around data store response times, part seems to be associated with queuing in the request dispatching subsystem. Part of it seems sort of correlated to the instance the request gets routed to. My code is relatively easy to benchmark, however the algorithm used by GAE to dispatch to my code is the part that Im trying to understand. It would be great is the dispatcher algorithm was published.

Comment: When I said "benchmark" I meant to measure the variables you are interested in, not just profile your code.  We cannot publish the algorithm because it frequently changes and because the input to the scheduler contains many measurements of your app's performance that are hard to track back directly to your code. The behavior is also affected by datastore performance which depends on many variables.  For more info on the scheduler, see the video of the talk that Justin Haugh and I did at Google I/O 2011 on scaling app engine apps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rP-kjrx9CRE